# C# - Changing Date and Time Format

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, format

I'm trying to create what the native messaging app has in terms of the date and time format changing depending on how many days have passed.

Let's say that I created a message and sent it today which is **03/01/2015 at 2:21 PM, Saturday**. The format for that should be:

```
.ToString("h:mm tt"); //2:21 p.m.
```

This is indicating that the message was sent today at 2:21 p.m and the format will not change until it's Sunday (Tomorrow).

This DateTime format will stay like this until tomorrow which is **04/01/2015, 12:00 AM ,Sunday**. Now the format should be:

```
.ToString("ddd"); //Sat
```

Now this is indicating that the message was sent yesterday on Saturday and the current format will not change until it's monday which will be **05/01/2015, 12:00 AM, Monday**.

To do this I'm currently using this function:

```
  public static string GetVisibleTime(DateTime time)
    {
        DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan totalSpan = (timeNow - time);
        if (totalSpan.TotalHours < 24)
        {
            return time.ToShortTimeString();
        }
        if (totalSpan.TotalDays < 7)
        {
            return time.ToString("ddd");
        }
        if (totalSpan.TotalDays < 14)
        {
            return time.ToString("ddd/MMM");
        }
        if (totalSpan.TotalDays < 365 && time.Year == timeNow.Year)
        {
            return time.ToString("MM/yy");
        }
        return time.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
    }
```

### My Problem

Now let's say I created and sent my message today at **2:35 p.m. on 03/01/2015** and tomorrow which will be 04/01/2015, I check to see what the format is at around 12:20 p.m. The format will still be 2:35 p.m. (in h:mm tt) and will not change. The only time the format will change is after it passes 2:35 p.m. on 04/01/2015. I want the format to change when it's the next day and not needing to wait until todays time or date matches yesterdays time or date in order for it to change. Like mentioned before, I'm trying to get it to work just like the native messaging app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the condition that is being evaluated.  Instead of checking elapsed time, check for same date.

Replace:

```
if (totalSpan.TotalHours < 24)
```

With this:

```
if (time.Date == timeNow.Date)
```

That way, the short time string will only appear if the date has not changed.  Once you pass midnight, it will fall through to the next condition.

Comment: That didn't work. Same problem. I have to wait till the date/time passes until the format changes. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure you're not facing some weird time zone issues? I agree with answer provided by Matt.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek how would I know if I'm facing any weird time zone issues?

Comment: Is everything happening in the same time zone? Are you normalizing your `DateTime` instances to UTC? Dealing with time in programming is not an easy task and there is a lot to think about.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Everything is happening in the same timezone. The code above is the only code I have in terms of changing time format.

Comment: If it helps, I test it by changing the date and time from the phone and seeing if the format will be applied. Could there be a problem with this?

Comment: @F4z The time zone of your server may be different from the time zone of user. So while comparing your server time(TimeZone1) with your client time(Timeone2) may give some different result. So make sure they are handled in a proper way. Also, for your above problem Matt's solution should work, make sure that everything else is fine.

Comment: I was answering from the perspective of a Windows Phone application, where the code shown is running on the device itself, and the time passed in was also generated from that device, or in the same time zone as that device.  In that scenario, using DateTime.Now to compare the local time of the phone is fine.